# Training and Validation loss are same but not decreasing for LSTM model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a timeseries data and I am doing univariate forecasting using stacked LSTM without any activation function, Like following.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(window_6, features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(200))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Also, I used ADAM optimizer and MSE loss, with 128 batch size and 500 epochs, and 500 steps per epoch.

```
loss_ = PlotLossesKeras()
model.fit(X1, y1, batch_size= 128, epochs=500, validation_split = 0.2, steps_per_epoch = 500, shuffle=True, callbacks=[loss_])
The loss plot looks like this:
```

[image: Plot]

```
Loss
    training             (min:   76.334, max: 1568.067, cur:   77.816)
    validation           (min:   83.637, max:  382.949, cur:   84.288)
500/500 [==============================] - 5s 9ms/step - loss: 77.8162 - val_loss: 84.2875
```

My questions:

1. Is this model overfit/underfit/Normal fit?
2. The current loss is 77 and validation loss is 84. How I can reduce loss to below 10?

Need suggestions. Open for any critique. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using LSTM without any activation function? My guess would be that your model is too simple to learn on this kind of problem. I would suggest you to start with only one LSTM layer and use ReLU as activation.

Comment: Thanks. But if I am not wrong, LSTM by default use tanh function. Right? So, If I am using ReLU activation function, Isn't it means that I am forcing my LSTM model to use ReLU activation instead of tanh function? Correct me if I am wrong. Also, the data is hourly Heart rate values of patient. Like 98.0, 93.0, 95.0, 102.0, etc. So if I use only one layer, will the model learn all the trend in the data? Please note I used split_sequence() function from this **Blog: (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting)** to prepare my data with 6 window size.

Comment: Yes, you are right, LSTM uses tanh activation by default. Is hourly heart rate the only feature you are using?

Comment: I have about 5 vitals, Heart rate, O2Sat, Temperature, Systolic Blood Pressure, Respiration, all are timeseries, and the data is recorded at hourly base. So, I will make total 5 univariate LSTM models to predict the 7th hour value of each vital using 6 hour previous data. (That's why I used the 6 window using split_sequence function). Then I will apply a logic on the predicted 5 outputs, and will tell if the disease will happen or not.